# Что происходит с переменной, возвращаемой из функции, если ее не сохранить?

Tags: c++, c

Что станет с переменной, которую вернут из функции, но не сохранят(Как в примере ниже)? Она будет лежать на стеке, или компилятор ее не будет возвращать?

```
int example(int i){
     return i;
}

int main(){
     int foo = 1;
     example(foo);
}
```

Comment: почитайте:  https://ravesli.com/urok-105-stek-i-kucha/

Comment: В диапазоне памяти той переменной будет записан рандомный мусор, пока вы явно не запишете в нее какое то значение.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых, не бывает никакого "возвращения переменной" из функции (если речь не идет о возвращении ссылок). Из функции возвращается *значение*, а не "переменная". К той переменной, которая была указана в `return` это значение никак не привязано. Сама переменная никому не нужна - она будет уничтожена при выходе из функции.

Во-вторых, как все это происходит внутри зависит от реализации и от типа возвращаемого значения и еще массы технических деталей. Значения скалярных типов обычно возвращаются через регистры процессора, т.е. никакого "стека" тут не замешано вообще. Значения более крупных типов могут размещаться в стеке, но могут быть подвергнуты (или не подвергнуты) оптимизации (RVO).

Но в любом случае - если вы игнорируете возвращаемое значение, то оно игнорируется. Никаких негативных последствий (вроде "утечки стека" или еще чего-то в этом роде) у такого игнорирования нет.